# How to let user select a coordinate in a map?

Tags: android, maps

Google search suggests using [PlacePicker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker#introduction) but the import fails at `location` using API 23 and the appropriate dependency in gradle `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"`

`import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;`

It seems this package is deprecated and not available anymore. How can I prompt the user to select an arbitrary point in a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently only using `gcm`, and you need to use `location`.

Put this in your dependencies in your build.gradle, and your import will resolve successfully:

```
dependencies {
    //.......
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
}
```

More details: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project